# Builder cannot be converted to HttpRequest

Tags: java, java-http-client

Trying to make a get request in Java 17 using HttpClient. All documentation I find tells me I should be able to do:

```java
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
URI uri = new URI("https://postman-echo.com/get");
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri);
```

However, I get an error

```
XmlTools.java:44: error: incompatible types: Builder cannot be converted to HttpRequest
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri);
                                                    ^
```

If I change the last line to

```java
Builder request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri);
```

then this error disappears, but the next part fails

```java
try {
    HttpResponse<InputStream> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofInputStream());
}
```

```
XmlTools.java:50: error: incompatible types: Builder cannot be converted to HttpRequest
            HttpResponse<InputStream> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofInputStream());
                                                             ^
```

Verbose compile gives me

```
XmlTools.java:50: error: method send in class HttpClient cannot be applied to given types;
            HttpResponse<InputStream> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofInputStream());
                                                       ^
  required: HttpRequest,BodyHandler<T>
  found:    Builder,BodyHandler<InputStream>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (argument mismatch; Builder cannot be converted to HttpRequest)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>send(HttpRequest,BodyHandler<T>)
1 error
```

One other thing I noticed, not sure if related, is that I'm unable to stack methods like so:

```java
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
  .uri(new URI("https://postman-echo.com/get"))
  .headers("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2")
  .GET()
  .build();
```

Am I in a wrong environment? I'm using OpenJDK on Windows.

Edit: Yea, it was user error. I should've copy/pasted instead of trying to pick out what I need. Thanks for your time.

Comment: "All documentation I find tells me I should be able to do" - could you point to *any* documentation that actually suggests you should be able to do that? I wouldn't expect you to be able to - I'd expect you to have to call `build()` at the end, and that all documentation would show that. (Additionally you say that you're "unable to stack methods" but you haven't told us what happens when you try.)

Answer (score 4):

`HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri)` returns an `HttpRequest.Builder`. You have to call `.build` method to create the actual `HttpRequest` instance:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(uri).build();
```

You could learn about the Builder design pattern [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder).